# NDIS 5/6 driver with tcp/ip stack, is there code?

Tags: tcp, driver, kernel, ndis

I'm trying to write a windows kernel driver which requires tcp/ip communication using NDIS 5/6. Since it will use NDIS, as I understand it, it needs it's own tcp/ip stack implementation.

Could anyone point me in the direction of an implementation of this, or something close to it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement your own TCP/IP stack!

First, are you sure that this needs to be done in a driver?  All your complex code and business logic should usually be in a usermode application or service.  Drivers are mostly meant to be very simple wrappers around hardware.  This rule isn't just some abstract principle either — it's much easier to write usermode code, where you can use a familiar debugger and the much-broader set of Win32 APIs.  You'll solve your problem sooner if you can move most of your code to usermode.

If you really must do TCP socket I/O in kernel mode, then you should use [Winsock Kernel (WSK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556958%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  WSK allows you to open a socket, similar to Winsock in usermode.  (Although the usermode Winsock API has more options and features; WSK is bare-bones).

WSK is available on Windows Vista and later.  If you must support Windows XP, then you need to use TDI.  TDI is much harder to get right; I don't reccomend using it if you can avoid it.